# Testing apps.py in django

Tags: django, unit-testing, code-coverage

How can I write a test to cover my apps.py files for each model in a django application? I need 100% code coverage and cannot figure out how to test these files. Example of one of my apps.py files:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ReportsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'reports'
```

Comment: Did you setup this properly? You can have that appconfig as default if you specify it in the `__init__.py` file of the app (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#for-application-authors )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.test import TestCase
from reports.apps import ReportsConfig


class ReportsConfigTest(TestCase):
    def test_apps(self):
        self.assertEqual(ReportsConfig.name, 'reports')
        self.assertEqual(apps.get_app_config('reports').name, 'reports')
```

Comment: for some reason this is not covering target code... Yet it test's it correctly because it definitely access application name variable... weird :/